# How do I upgrade my asp.net mvc2 project to asp.net mvc3 in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3

I have started the process of upgrading my mvc projects from 2 to 3 using this guide: http://mattsieker.com/index.php/2010/11/21/converting-asp-net-mvc2-project-to-mvc3/.

So far, I have just removed the old reference to system.web.mvc. When I looked for System.Web.MVC (version 3) it wasn't listed. I could only find version 2.

I know that I have 3 installed. I used the web platform installer to download and install mvc3. In VS2010 I do have the option to make an MVC3 project.

How do i add the reference to system.web.mvc V3? Where do i look?

Comment: Have you restarted visual studios since the mvc version 3 install?

Comment: maybe it help you -> C:\Program Files\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 3\Assemblies\

Comment: @Austin M - yes I have restarted.

Comment: @Kim Tranjan - Yes, I have a similar path (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 3\Assemblies\System.Web.Mvc.dll) Isn't that supposed to show up in the "Add Reference > .NET" List of available DLLs?

Comment: unfortunately nope, in my project I added the reference following this path

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Re-target your web project for .NET 4.0 before being able to see `System.Web.Mvc, Version 3.0.0.0` in the references list.

Comment: The project has always been a .NET 4 project. All of my view use `<%: Model.varName %>`

Comment: @quakkels, no problem then, once you install ASP.NET MVC 3 on your machine you would be able to select this assembly in the references list (from the GAC).

Comment: I'm confused. I thought that if I can create a MVC3 project from the filemenu that it was already installed. I'm pretty sure when I used Web Platform Installer to download and install MVC3 that it installed it on my computer.

Comment: @quakkels, quite honestly I've never used the Web Platform Installer. I always prefer to download and install the MSI. So then you could probably go look for the assembly in the "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 3\Assemblies\" folder.

Answer (score 4):

There is a tool that you can use to upgrade your projects. You just point it at the .csproj file and it will update your project to ASP.NET MVC 3:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/marcinon/archive/2011/01/13/mvc-3-project-upgrade-tool.aspx

Answer (score 3):

You should follow this:

http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/mvc3-release-notes#upgrading

This is very good instruction and definitely more detailed.

Comment: Thank you for the link. it is definitely more detailed. But, I still get hung up on step 5 as my initial question describes.

Comment: @quakkels: You can reference assembly in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 3\Assemblies. System.Web.Mvc.dll is located there.

Comment: Is there a way to get that to show in the list found here : "References > Add Reference > .NET"???

Comment: @quakkels: I am not sure. As far as I remember, when I installed MVC 3, I didn't have it there too. I uninstalled MVC 2, MVC 3 and then installed it again. I also used Web Platform Installer.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem mentioned above where I installed MVC 3 and couldn't find the reference to System.Web.MVC version 3.0.0.0 in the add references dialog. The solution was simple: The assemblies in the dialog box weren't all ordered alphabetically, so I actually did have the appropriate reference to System.Web.Mvc available in the dialog, but it was shown out of order.

I scrolled down in the list past the section with the other System.Web dlls and eventually found System.Web.MVC, version 3.0.0.0.

I am using Visual Web Developer Express 2010.

EDIT: The "Add References" dialog in VS has sortable columns, so if you sort by name it helps in situations like this. It's confusing that VS doesn't sort the assemblies in name order by default, but now you know.

Answer (score 0):

in best practice you need a tool who someone made on MSDN especially for upgrade MVC 2 project to MVC 3.

the thing you need to check that :-

the all dll should be update if you confused just create new MVC 3 project and check out all dll a MVC 3 project should have.

you need to check that target to MVC 3 in both web.config :- first stored in main directory and second in Views directory

it is enough to solve the situation when upgrade from MVC 2 to MVC 3